# How to declare a depended relationship between functions in ts?

Tags: typescript

sorry for the confusing title,i'm not sure how to explain my question clearly.
currently, i'm try to implement a method which could parse a object from a xml.
the xml (use xml-js to translate to js) looks like this

```
interface OpmlElement {
  attributes: {
    text:string
  },
  elements:OpmlElement[]
}
```

the target object look like this

```
interface ParsedTestCase {
    title?: string;
    suites?: string[];
}
```

so, i want to declare some kind of parser to parse this xml. idefine some kind of parser

```
const elementParserTable= [
  {
        check: (e:OpmlElement) => getText(e).startsWith("tt:"),
        takeValue: (e:OpmlElement) => getText(e),
        cb: (v:string)=> {
          testcase.title=v
        }
  } ,
  {
        check: (e:OpmlElement) => getText(e).startsWith("ts:"),
        takeValue: (e:OpmlElement) =>getText(e).split(","),
        cb: (v:string[])=> {
          testcase.suites=v
        }
  },
]
```

the first question is when i use like above

```
const elements:OpmlElement[]=[]

for (const e of elements) {
    for (const elementParser of elementParserTable) {
        if (elementParser.check(e)) {
            elementParser.cb(elementParser.takeValue(e));
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

ts complains that
[image]

```
Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & string[]'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & string[]'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
```

how could i avoid this?
and the second question is: is there some way to constrain the elementParser in elementParserTable to make sure that the return type of takeValue function is the cb function's parameter type?

Comment: Are there actually only two elements parsers in the array or is this just an example?

Comment: as a example, it could be any number of element parser,and each parser's type could be different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can avoid your error without casting ( `elementParser.cb(elementParser.takeValue(e) as any` ).

To answer the second question, you can make sure that the return type of take value is cb's parameter with a generic interface. For example:

```
interface ElementParser<T> {
    check: (e: OpmlElement) => boolean,
    takeValue: (e: OpmlElement) => T,
    cb: (v: T) => void
}

const elementParserTable: Array<ElementParser<string> | ElementParser<string[]>> = [...]
```

Of course, all of this is just a crappy workaround of the fact that typescript does not have existential types.

Comment: as any..is some kind of hack,i;m little confusing why this error happen.

Comment: This is due to the effect of type inference over param of functions. I remember some detail explanation by jcalz, lemme search it for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type

Comment: @hackape the solution to this problem is called existential types, but ts does not have it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend combine `takeValue` and `cb` at one method.

```
const elementParserTable= [
  {
    check: (e: OpmlElement) => getText(e).startsWith("tt:"),
    cb: (e: OpmlElement) => {
      testcase.title = getText(e);
    },
  },
  {
    check: (e: OpmlElement) => getText(e).startsWith("ts:"),
    cb: (e: OpmlElement)=> {
      testcase.suites = getText(e).split(",");
    },
  },
];
```

And usage:

```
const elements: OpmlElement[] = [];

for (const e of elements) {
  for (const elementParser of elementParserTable) {
    if (elementParser.check(e)) {
      elementParser.cb(e);

      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

I think you can try combine `check`, `takeValue` and `cb` at one method. But I'm not sure if that's your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do another function to let typescript know if it's a string

```
    isTitle(titleOrSuite:string|string[]) titleOrSuite is string{
       return typeof titleOrSuite === "string";
    }
```

```
const elementParserTable= [
  {
        check: (e:OpmlElement) => getText(e).startsWith("tt:"),
        takeValue: (e:OpmlElement) => getText(e),
        cb: (v:string|string[])=> isTitle(v) ? testcase.title=v : testcase.suites=v      
  } ,
  {
        check: (e:OpmlElement) => getText(e).startsWith("ts:"),
        takeValue: (e:OpmlElement) =>getText(e).split(","),
        cb: (v:string|string[])=> isTitle(v) ? testcase.title=v : testcase.suites=v
  },
]
```